# Converting date from string to int in Java

Tags: java, string, date, int, simpledateformat

I want to convert a string of date value(January 27) to 01/27. I know I can do this using the SimpleDateFormat class or creating a bunch of if-else statements, but I was wondering if there was another way to convert it without using the SimpleDateFormat class or creating if-else statements.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/ Check this out

Comment: Using a class is easy and I can do it using that, but I want to learn a different way as well.

Comment: Not only are there **multiple** ways to do this, your desired output is a `String` (`01/27` is not an `int`).

Comment: *"way to convert it without using the SimpleDateFormat"* - Yes, use a `DateTimeFormatter` - it's time for `SimpleDateFormat` to die

Comment: Do you think it is possible to list other ways? You don't have to explain them, I would like to research them on my own so I can improve. And yup, my mistake

Comment: Populate a `Map` with all of the month names as keys, iterate [`Month.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#values--) and use that to get the `int` value for a name. There are probably other ways. Best of luck!

Comment: Use two `DateTimeFormatter` objects - one to parse and one to format.  I'm assuming you actually want a `String` not an `int` as output.

Comment: Your title says convert from a string, but the body of your Question does not specify. Clarify by editing.

Comment: *Using a class is easy*. Yes, exactly. Do that. Everything else will make life worse for those maintaining your code after you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
MonthDay
.parse(
    "January 27" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM d").withLocale( Locale.US )
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd") 
)
```

## `MonthDay`

There is a class for that: `MonthDay`.

Parse a standard ISO 8601 string.

```
String input = "--01-23" ;
MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.parse( input ) ;
```

Generate text in standard format.

```
String output = MonthDay.toString() ;
```

For your custom format, define a custom formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( "--01-23" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd") ;
String output = md.format( f ) ;
```

> 01/23

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UrG36g).

Comment: sn24, if you need the numbers, you can get them from `monthDay.getMonthValue()` and `monthDay.getDayOfMonth()`.